# It-cleft sentence or what?

Tags: grammar

I couldn't figure out the logic of this sentence. I heard it in a dialogue in a film.I have never seen such a pattern in grammar books. But as a result of my researches, I saw that it was examined in the subject of "it cleft". but unfortunately I did not understand this pattern again.I would be very happy if you could help me.

**'' i know what it is you need ??? ''**

Comment: I know who it is you hired.  Very common construction.

Comment: Would it be clearer if the optional "that" were included? _I know what it is that you need_.

Comment: Including optional ***it is** [that]* in the cited context is a relatively uncommon (but certainly not *rare*) stylistic choice. The effect of which is to ***emphasize*** the significance of the thing known, since it's effectively been referenced ***twice*** (initially by ***what***, then again by ***it***).

Comment: What needs explanation is "it is".

Comment: I think that to some extent, the sequence ***what it is*** has become "grammaticalized" so that it's now almost seen as a complete syntactic unit all on its own. And *that's* part of what encourages the cited use. Another effect of this process is that if we're see those three words as "self-contained", it's easier to understand the increasing tendency to repeat the verb, in *What it is **is** that those three words have taken on a life of their own, beyond the reach of pedants*.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the following sentence:

> (1) You need food.

If we turn this sentence into an *it*-cleft, it becomes:

> (2) It is food that you need.

And if we turn this *it*-cleft into a "*wh-* question," we get:

> (3) What is it that you need?

Here, in (3), we have what's called "subject-auxiliary inversion"—the auxiliary (*is*) moves to a position that precedes the subject (*it*). **But if we embed a *wh-* question into a declarative sentence, there is no inversion (at least in Standard English)**. So, if we embed (3) into a declarative sentence, we would get something like (4), where there is no inversion:

> (4) I know what **it is** that you need.

The complementizer (*that*) is optional in this sentence, so we can change this to:

> (4') I know what it is you need.

And that's basically the sentence you were asking about, or at least a declarative version of it. Depending on the intonation (or punctuation in writing), the sentence in (4') can become a question without any change in word order, in which case it may mean what DrMoishe Pippik suggested in an earlier answer: "Do you think that I know what it is that you need??"

Answer (score 0):

Consider the clause, "it is what you need." Taken as a sentence, it's easily understood -- the item referred to by "it" is an item that you need.

Inverting the order to, "what is it you need?" makes it a question.

Looking at the whole, "I know what it is you need," would be a simple statement that I know the item you need.

Ah! But with the reiterated question marks, the speaker is asking, "***I*** know what it is you need???" I.E., "Do you think that ***I*** know what it is that you need???"